# bash unary operator expected error

Tags: bash, grep

This is the script I came up with

```
#!/bin/bash

expression=$1
field=$2
if [ -z "$expression" ]; then
echo "expression is missing"
exit 1
fi

if [ -f /home/miked/table ]; then
  if [ -f table ] && [ grep "$expression table" ]; then
    grep "$expression" table | cut -d: -f${2:-3} | clipit
  else
    echo "no match found"
  fi
else
  echo "there is no table file"
fi
```

As a matter of fact I know how to fix it, but I don't know why
it's fixed.

If I remove the space between `grep` and `"`, all is working fine, I just can't seem to understand why.

If I do `grep something file` directly to the command line, it's working good. Why do I to stick the `grep` to the `"` in the script?

Comment: does it work if you do `[ \`grep $expression table\` ]`?

Comment: yes but i need explanation here

Comment: Side note, not really related to question: why do you first check if `/home/miked/table` exists, but then you work with `table` in the current directory?

Comment: @TallChuck This tests if the output of `grep` is non-zero, which may look like the same as checking the exit status in this case, but it doesn't actually tell you if grep was successful

Comment: and what i wrote doesnt check if it is non-zero?

Comment: This is a good overview of tests and conditionals in Bash: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: what i thought is that grep will first evaluates "$expression table" then if it is non-zero it will exit 0 which is good but if its zero it exit 1 which pass to... [ ] test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151308/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-jaindoe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to wrap `grep` call inside square brackets. `[` is alias to `test` command (in general, however most shells replicate that using builtin). You can see syntax of that command using `man test`. What you want do is to check if `$expression table` exist in some file, so instead you need to write it as:

```
#!/bin/bash

expression="$1"
field="$2"
if [ -z "$expression" ]; then
  echo "expression is missing"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -f /home/miked/table ]; then
  if [ -f table ] && grep "$expression table"; then
    grep "$expression" table | cut -d: -f${2:-3} | clipit
  else
    echo "no match found"
  fi
else
  echo "there is no table file"
fi
```

---

However there are more problems with your script.

1. You print errors to `stdout` instead of `stderr` which makes them invisible when piping output of your script to other tools, instead you should use `echo "error" >&2`, ideally use separate function for that.
2. You pass only 1 argument to `grep` and I believe that there should be 2: `grep "$expression" table`.
3. Your first `grep` call will also print to `stdout` and I believe you want to surpass that, so instead use `-q` flag.
4. It is good idea to enable "exit on error" using `set -e` and "exit on pipe error" using `set -o pipefail`
5. You do not use outer file, so you can just remove check for that.
6. You do not use your `$field` variable.
7. Use guard clausules instead of `if`s for fatal error checking as it will make easier to refactor your script.

So whole file could be written as:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eo pipefail

perror() {
  echo "$1" >&2 && exit 1
}

expression=$1
field=${2:-3}
file=${3:table}

[ -z "$expression" ] || perror "expression is missing"
[ -f "$file" ] || perror "there is no '$file' file"

grep "$expression" "$file" | cut -d: -f"${field}" | clipit || perror "no match found"
```

Comment: `grep "$expression table"` in your first example doesn't work, grep requires two arguments. You point this out later, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. first script is just fix for author error. Second part is about all other problems with this script, and that problem is also mentioned (as we cannot be 100% sure what OP intentions were).

Comment: Fair enough. Notice that `set -e` comes with a lot of pitfalls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Thank you all. all the answers  was very helpful!

Comment: @BenjaminW. of course that `set -e` has some pitfalls, however in most occasions I would rather stop the script rather than allow it to quietly fail. Also I use ShellCheck for my scripts and that cover things like `local` assigns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `[ ]` at all here. You're interested in the exit status of grep and it gives you one already; to suppress its output, you can use the `-q` option:

```
if [ -f table ] && grep -q "$expression" table; then
```

The filename should not be within the quotes, either.

If you use `[ ]` without any test, it defaults to `-n`: "true if string is not empty". This test expects a single argument, which is why it seems to work for you if you remove the space: it just checks if the string `grep$expression table` expands to is non-zero, and it always is.

Comment: why grep "expression table" results in two arguments? i thought if it has a then grep exit status would be 0 which is good if there isnt a much it yield exit status of 1 which take me to else clause so why this line produce 2 arguments?

Comment: It's two arguments for `[ ]`: the first one is `grep`, the second one is `"$expression table"`.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things that could be done to fix this, your main problem is the following line:
 `if [ -f table ] && [ grep "$expression table" ]; then`

You've already tested if "table" exists, so you're doing it again and once it succeeds, the expression `[ grep "$expression table" ]` is being evaluated, which is broken down to `'[' grep 'expression table' ']'` which means essentially nothing.

You should instead use $() and evaluate the number of occurrences, or like Benjamin mentions, skip it altogether if that's what you want.

I would suggest something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
expression=$1
field=$2
table_file=/home/miked/table
if [ -z "$expression" ]; then
    echo "expression is missing"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -f $table_file ]; then
    if [ $(grep -q "$expression $table_file") -gt 0 ]; then
        grep "$expression" $table_file | cut -d: -f${2:-3} | clipit
    else
        echo "no match found"
    fi
else
    echo "there is no table file"
fi
```

Notice how we're still using a test, this could be condensed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
expression=$1
field=$2
table_file=/home/miked/table
if [ -z "$expression" ]; then
    echo "expression is missing"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -f $table_file ]; then
    grep -q $expression $table_file && grep "$expression" $table_file | cut -d: -f${2:-3} | clipit || echo "no match found"
else
    echo "there is no table file"
fi
```

Comment: This is really a prime use case for `grep -q`.